# Checkbox check/tick not showing up though checked attribute returns true

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a piece of code that creates check boxes in a table in a loop and calls their onclick function. In the onclick function, I try to populate a global array that will be a position holder for the checked check boxes of the table. Also if a row is checked, I have to sum the numbers in a text field of that row(I add this to a variable percentage) and if the variable crosses 100 I have to alert the user and ask him to enter values in the checkbox such that the sum is less than 100.

My problem is that each time I click a check box, the global array gets populated, sum is stored in the variable as expected, but **the 'tick' on the check box doesn't come/disappears immediately**.

How do I solve this issue?

Code:

```
    {
var tabId=document.getElementById("AmnestyTransTbl"); 
var tabrows = tabId.getElementsByTagName('tr');

var percentage=0,c,n;
var ar=[];
for(var i=1,c=2;i<=tabrows.length-3;i++,c=c+2)
{
// Create CheckBox
ar[i]=c;
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
checkBox.id='CB'.concat(i);
checkBox.onclick = function ()
{

var tabId1=document.getElementById("AmnestyTransTbl"); 
var rowInd=getRowIndex(this);

CBValue[rowInd]=this.checked;
 n=ar[rowInd-1];
 percentage=(parseInt(percentage) + parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value));
 if(parseInt(percentage)>100) 
 {
 alert("Amnesty Percentage,"+percentage+", greater than 0!. Plesase check again.");
 this.checked=false;
 }
 if(this.checked==false)
 percentage=parseInt(percentage)-parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value);
 }    }
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.appendChild(checkBox);
tabrows[i+1].cells[1].appendChild(td);
}

function getRowIndex(el)
{
while((el=el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'tr');
if (el)
return el.rowIndex;
}
```

Comment: May be this is causing it to be un checked....if(parseInt(percentage,10)>100) {
this.checked=false;
}

Comment: that uncheck happens only when percentage>100. if i first click on a checkbox for which the value of the text field being added(in that row ) is say 35, it shudnt go into that loop and uncheck the check box...or do you think i have made some mistake there?

Comment: I commented out the if condition and its block. It still apears uncheked..

Comment: plz post ur html code also?and full javascript code including function such as getRowIndex.and what is CBValue?

Comment: i have added the getRowIndex. The HTML is not coded directly, but is a part of a tool...

Comment: i have posted answer, try dat plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the culprit i guess,

Plz try replacing this

```
 if(parseInt(percentage,10)>100) {
              this.checked=false;
          }

          if(this.checked=false)
          {
               percentage=parseInt(percentage)-parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value);
          }
```

with  this

```
if(parseInt(percentage,10)>100) {
              this.checked=false;
          }
          else
          {
              this.checked=true;
          }

          if(this.checked==false)
          {
               percentage=parseInt(percentage)-parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value);
          }
```

Comment: hey Jade, thanks, that was an mistake , though it solved why percentage wasn't getting reduced on false value, our problem still exists- when i click the checkbox it still does not show the tick mark

Comment: @Neethusha i have updated my answer plz check and are u getting any javascript error from your code

Comment: pleasure 2 hear dat :) plz mark as answer if it solves the issue

Comment: although now what is happening is that when percentage>100 it throws an alert(that i have added). if there are 3 checkboxes have values 34,56,10 and if these 3 are selected it lets me submit a submit button. but if i go back and uncheck the row with 10, it throws alert saying percantage is 110( it should be 90)...

Comment: u want me to vote it?:-) yeah i will! but is it possible for you to help me with this one? i thought the if(this.checked==false) will solve it....

Comment: no dat's fine accept it as answer only if ur issue is resolved

Comment: @Neethusha well listen if u can, den mail me ur problem.I can look into it.With proper description about what u want ur code to do.

Comment: I can do that if that is what you want, or i just opened a new question with the issue I mentioned:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642871/html-javascript-checkbox-uncheck-after-checking-once-not-functioning-properly