# HTML/Javascript Checkbox uncheck after checking once not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a piece of code that creates check boxes in a table in a loop and calls their onclick function. In the onclick function, I try to populate a global array that will be a position holder for the checked check boxes of the table. Also if a row is checked, I have to sum the numbers in a text field of that row(I add this to a variable percentage) and if the variable crosses 100 I have to alert the user and ask him to enter values in the checkbox such that the sum is less than 100.

What is happening is that when percentage>100 it throws an alert(that i have added). if there are 3 checkboxes have values 34,56,10 and if these 3 are selected it lets me submit a submit button. but if i go back and uncheck the row with 10, it throws alert saying percantage is 110( it should be 90)

How do I solve this issue?

Code:

```
    var tabId = document.getElementById("AmnestyTransTbl");
    var tabrows = tabId.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    var percentage = 0,
        c, n;
    var ar = [];
    for (var i = 1, c = 2; i <= tabrows.length - 3; i++, c = c + 2) {
        // Create CheckBox
        ar[i] = c;
        var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
        checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkBox.id = 'CB'.concat(i);
        checkBox.onclick = function () {

            var tabId1 = document.getElementById("AmnestyTransTbl");
            var rowInd = getRowIndex(this);

            CBValue[rowInd] = this.checked;
            n = ar[rowInd - 1];
            percentage = (parseInt(percentage) + parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value));
            if (parseInt(percentage) > 100) {
                alert("Amnesty Percentage," + percentage + ", greater than 0!. Plesase check again.");
                this.checked = false;
            }
            if (this.checked == false) percentage = parseInt(percentage) - parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value);
        }
    }
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(checkBox);
    tabrows[i + 1].cells[1].appendChild(td);
    }

    function getRowIndex(el) {
        while ((el = el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'tr');
        if (el) return el.rowIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.....

```
    var tabId = document.getElementById("AmnestyTransTbl");
    var tabrows = tabId.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    var percentage = 0,
        c, n;
    var ar = [];
    for (var i = 1, c = 2; i <= tabrows.length - 3; i++, c = c + 2) {
        // Create CheckBox
        ar[i] = c;
        var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
        checkBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkBox.id = 'CB'.concat(i);
        checkBox.onclick = function () {

            var tabId1 = document.getElementById("AmnestyTransTbl");
            var rowInd = getRowIndex(this);

            CBValue[rowInd] = this.checked;
            n = ar[rowInd - 1];
            if (this.checked == false)
                percentage = parseInt(percentage) - parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value);
            else
                percentage = (parseInt(percentage) + parseInt(tabId1.getElementsByTagName("input")[n].value));
            if (parseInt(percentage) > 100) {
                alert("Amnesty Percentage," + percentage + ", greater than 0!. Plesase check again.");
                this.checked = false;
            }

        }
    }
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(checkBox);
    tabrows[i + 1].cells[1].appendChild(td);
    }

    function getRowIndex(el) {
        while ((el = el.parentNode) && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'tr');
        if (el) return el.rowIndex;
    }
```

Comment: No this did not work- it is not subtracting when the current checkbox row exceeds 100...

Comment: Hey I added one more subtract statement in the if (parseInt(percentage) > 100) block and now it works just fine! Thanks a lot.